# Rancher container starts with {"NetworkDisabled": true} by default

Tags: jenkins, amazon-eks, docker-network, rancher

I use Jenkins cloud deployed by aws rancher. When I try to inspect docker network settings I see `{"NetworkDisabled": true}` by default. I am not able to figure out how to enable it.

My container always starts with `{"NetworkDisabled": true}`. Because of this, my selenium tests are not able to connect to the chrome container.

Is there anyway to make this parameter false and where should I update the config?

Comment: Hi! Are you using AWS EKS? Would this question benefit from the `aws-eks` [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)?

Comment: @tjheslin1 Yes, I use AWS EKS